# Deployment issues after changing schema tables in ROR Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

After changing my GuideIndustry model to ConnectIndustry through find and replace, I have been getting the error below on the release log preventing me from deploying my rails app onto heroku. Is there anyway to have rails override all the files heroku is using? My local copy of all the files and the schema are working just fine. I have tried using the heroku pg:reset and then heroku run rake db:migrate.

```
== 20190215035620 AddArticleIdToConnectIndustry: migrating ====================
-- add_column(:connect_industries, :article_id, :integer)
   (2.4ms)  ALTER TABLE "connect_industries" ADD "article_id" integer
   (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
   (1.2ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(3329669382293610510)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "connect_industries" does not exist
```

Update:
Through find and replace and a manual file name change, i edited the create GuideIndustry table migration to be as follows:

```
class CreateConnectIndustries < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :connect_industries do |t|
      t.integer :guide_id
      t.integer :industry_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you have replaced GuideIndustry to ConnecteIndustry in `schema.rb` or within a previous migration when you did find and replace, nop? If you want to change the name of your model, you have to create a migration to change the name of the table

Comment: If you have no production data in heroku you could drop the entire db and recreate it. Otherwise as mentioned this should have been done in a migration

Comment: i edited the existing create GuideIndustry table migration to be create ConnectIndustry. Wouldn't that do the same as creating a separate migration to rename the table if the database is reset?

Comment: The error is raised by Postgres so your connect_industries table not exists in your database and you want to add a column within in your `AddArticleId` migration. If you change the name in the previous migration, ActiveRecord will looking for ConnectIndustry but in your DB, ConnectIndustry doesn't exist because you didn't create the migration to tell to Postgres that guide_industries is now connect_industries. As mentioned by @engineersmnky you should recreate your DB if it's empty, or revert your changes in db folder, then create a migration to change the name before changing the structure

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I deleted the AddArticleId migrations and just edited the CreateConnectIndustry migration to have the article_id column.